# Is there a way to quickly disable caching for all views? (for dev work)

Tags: views, caching

Is there a variable/other way to quickly disable all views caching when working on a dev server?  I have a lot of views which have different caching settings, and there are times when I am doing testing that I would just like to turn all views caching off, similar to the way that you can turn CSS/JS aggregation off.

I found [that the Views module itself has its own cache](https://www.drupal.org/node/1917566) in the documentation, but this is not the caching for individual views-- and the caching for each individual view is what I want to turn off.

Comment: +1. Interesting question asked before: [How to disable/enable cache of all views programmatically?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/161408/how-to-disable-enable-cache-of-all-views-programmatically). What is described here [How to disable caching in Drupal 7 Views module](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/drupal-7/views-module-tutorial/disable-view-cache) does not have the desired effect and what you refer to here [Disable Views caching](https://www.drupal.org/node/1917566) says that mentioned setting in Views only caches meta-data about Views or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

If You ask about drupal 7 can use

`cache_clear_all('*', 'cache_views', TRUE);`

in template file.

Refreshing page that is using the file will clear all views cache.